# pgfplots .eps figures problems

Tags: pgfplots, eps, tikz-external, journal

I generated .eps figures with pgfplots.

```
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
                                        -halt-on-error
                                        -interaction=batchmode
                                        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
                                        && pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

I then replace the tikz code with \includegraphic{.eps}.

I have problems when I upload the generated eps figures to some journal submission applications (scholarone manuscript). Has anyone encountered this problem?

Also, the .eps figures generated with Latexdraw (option export) also cause problems.

If I convert the eps to pdf figures and them back to eps with pdftops it still not works.

Comment: Could you give a detailed description of your issue, because, with the current information that you have provided it is really difficult to find the root-cause per se.

Comment: Please also mention how you produced the .eps figures. Does your script (pgf or LaTeXdraw) directly produce eps, or you they give you pdf, from which you re-convert to eps with some software/tool ?

Comment: It is rather likely that the journal will not allow you make system calls.  Please provide details of the error messages.

Comment: Well, the compiler of the journal central is tex ->dvipdf. It compiles without error to dvi but it stops there without a pdf output. I mean, for uploading the .tex, I comment the tikz code and replace it by includegraphics where I include the generated .eps figure. The problem is that the generated .eps figure causes problems when compiling and I do not know why.

Comment: From the submission guide ~~ Images ~~ Remove thumbnails from image files ~~ Verify your images are in single, flattened layer.. I guess its possible you are breaking one or both of those "rules" since EPS can include embedded preview thumbnail. You will likely need to use another graphics tool to check and correct the .eps. I don't have a recommendation but there are many freely available, and you may already have some in your tool chain.

Comment: In case you don't have the latex guide here is a related link http://mchelp.manuscriptcentral.com/gethelpnow/tutorials/authorlatexfileupload.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. One must upload the bibliography inside the latex document. Not with a .bib.

Uploading the .bib file is OK when you are not calling to .eps files but it fails if your .tex refers to .eps files.